# Unable to share text on Instagram in ios 5

Tags: iphone, instagram

I used following code, and instagram app displays my photo but text what I want to share dosen't display.

I used annotation property, but it's not working. I don't know where is wrong ?

instagram version : 3.5.0

my iphone version : 5.0.1

xcode version     : 4.6

Regards.

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
{       
    NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.igo"];
    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath];        
    NSURL *imageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: urlString];

    self.docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:imageUrl usingDelegate:self];
    self.docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    self.docController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"I want to share this text" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];

    [self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect: self.view.frame inView: self.view animated: YES ];

}
```

Comment: thanks. but my question is sharing text is not working by "  self.docController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"I want to share this text" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];  ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Instagram forum, 3rd party captions broke in the latest (3.5) release.

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/instagram-api-developers/wLfX0cJUUyM/discussion

See the following comment from Mike Krieger acknowledging the bug:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/instagram-api-developers/wLfX0cJUUyM/SK_m4IJ3wn8J

Comment: you are right. In new version (3.5.1 : released at May 7), above bug fixed. Thanks @Kyle.